# How to logout after killing all activities?

Tags: android, android-navigation

On my App, I have the following process to log on a user:

- The user enters its credentials on the `MainActivity` and is redirected to `HomeActivity` using that code for navigation:

  ```
  Intent accueilIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
  accueilIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                         | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  finish();
  startActivity(accueilIntent);
  ```
- When the user is on the `HomeActivity`, he is able to log out thanks to a log out button. Since the event is fired, I would like to kill all  activities  and redirect the user to the login activity (`MainActivity`). So The code which is fired on the event is the following:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- The user is well redirected to the `MainPage`. Then  when I press the home button to get back on the Android home screen and then I come back to the App, the right `MainActivity` appears. However, when I press the native back button to return to the android home screen and then I come back to the App, the `HomeActivity` appears (the one that should be destroyed before) and not the `MainActivity`.

Does anyone can tell me why I'm coming back to `HomeActivity` and not `MainActivity` in this case?

Comment: Try to add `finish();` after your `startIntent()` call to finish the current activity.

Comment: Which is launcher activity in your applications manifest.xml ? MainActivity or HomeActivity ?

Comment: @ryguy I've tried and also printed to state, when I quit the HomeActivity, it is destroyed. But still the same behavior

Comment: @pcj the launcher is MainActivity

Comment: Interesting, did the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag help? (as suggested by Prachi)

Comment: yes it works actually :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1] add `finish()` before `startActivity()`

2] Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to come back to MainAcitvity when he presses back button on HomeActivity, the parent of HomeActivity should be MainActivity.

In your manifest.xml file, in HomeActivity's  tag add this :

```
<activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" > 

....
</activity>
```